# Writing a matrix expansion as a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, matrices, power-series

Suppose I have two matrices $A$ and $B$. I want to simplify the expression $(1-A)^n - (1-B)^n$. If I plug this into Wolfram alpha, it says that about $A = B$, this has a series expansion of $$\sum_{n > 0} (-1)^n (A - B)^n.$$ This looks good, since I want to represent $(1-A)^n - (1-B)^n$ in terms of $(A-B)$. The formula works for $n=1$, but putting in $n=2$, it fails. I don't see how Wolfram has obtained this expression. Note that I've assumed $$\sum_{n > 0} (-1)^n (A-B)^n = \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^j (A-B)^j.$$

Here is a link to the wolfram page: - 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=write+(1-A)%5En+-+(1-B)%5En+as+power+series+about+A%3DB

Comment: A scalar minus a matrix is not well defined. Do you mean identity matrix or a matrix filled with ones or something third?

Comment: @mathreadler I would write it as the identity operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a series expansion, I guess it suffices to expand the expression binomially and simplify.

$$
(I - A)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k} I^{n - k}A^k = \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} A^k.
$$

Similarly,

$$
(I - B)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k} B^k.
$$

Thus,

$$
(I - A)^n - (I - B)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (A^k - B^k).
$$

Comment: You're welcome.